# How can I get only the latest file/files created/modified on S3 location through python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

using boto i tried the below code :

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection('XXX', 'YYYY')

bucket = conn.get_bucket('myBucket')

file_list = bucket.list('just/a/prefix/')
```

but am unable to get the length of the list or the last element of the file_list as it is a BucketListResultSet type ,please suggest a solution for this scenario

Comment: Do you only want to list all the files on given bucket having specified prefix? Or there are some more expectations (like getting only the latest files or so).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to use `boto` library, which is rather obsolete and not maintained. The number of
issues with this library is growing.

Better use currently developed `boto3`.

First, let us define parameters of our search:

```
>>> bucket_name = "bucket_of_m"
>>> prefix = "region/cz/"
```

Do import `boto3` and create s3 representing S3 resource:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
```

Get the bucket:

```
>>> bucket = s3.Bucket(name=bucket_name)
>>> bucket
s3.Bucket(name='bucket_of_m')
```

Define filter for objects with given prefix:

```
>>> res = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix)
>>> res
s3.Bucket.objectsCollection(s3.Bucket(name='bucket_of_m'), s3.ObjectSummary)
```

and iterate over it:

```
>>> for obj in res:
...     print obj.key
...     print obj.size
...     print obj.last_modified
...
```

Each `obj` is ObjectSummary (not Object itself), but it holds enought to learn something about it

```
>>> obj
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_of_m', key=u'region/cz/Ostrava/Nadrazni.txt')
>>> type(obj)
boto3.resources.factory.s3.ObjectSummary
```

You can get Object from it and use it as you need:

```
>>> o = obj.Object()
>>> o
s3.Object(bucket_name='bucket_of_m', key=u'region/cz/rodos/fusion/AdvancedDataFusion.xml')
```

There are not so many options for filtering, but prefix is available.

Comment: Jan Thanks for pointing to the right direction .....first it was totally confusing to use the boto3 but after settingup the aws configure it became all easy and chill..:>

Comment: @meenakshi I know, what you are talking about, using old `boto` - at least for S3, used to be much simpler. You may see related issue on this topic: [`boto3` is not a replacement of `boto` (yet?)](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3306). If you follow the discussion, author of original boto Mitch Garnaat states that clearly, **you have to switch to `boto3`, "You Can't Go Home Again"**

Answer (score 3):

*As an addendum to [Jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36343469):*

---

Seems that the boto3 library has changed in the meantime and currently (version 1.6.19 at the time of writing) offers [more parameters for the `filter` method](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=resource#S3.Bucket.objects):

> ```
> object_summary_iterator = bucket.objects.filter(
>     Delimiter='string',
>     EncodingType='url',
>     Marker='string',
>     MaxKeys=123,
>     Prefix='string',
>     RequestPayer='requester'
> )
> ```

Three useful parameters to limit the number of entries for your scenario are `Marker`, `MaxKeys` and `Prefix`:

> **Marker** (*string*) -- Specifies the key to start with when listing
>   objects in a bucket.
>   **MaxKeys** (*integer*) -- Sets the maximum number of
>   keys returned in the response. The response might contain fewer keys
>   but will never contain more.
>   **Prefix** (*string*) -- Limits the response to
>   keys that begin with the specified prefix.

Two notes:

- The key you specify for **Marker** will *not* be included in the result, i.e. the listing starts from the key *following* the one you specify as Marker.
- The boto3 library is performing automatic *pagination* on the results. The size of each page is determined by the **MaxKeys** parameter of the filter function (defaulting to 1000).

  If you iterate over the `s3.Bucket.objectsCollection` object for more than that, it will *automatically* download the next page. While this is generally useful, it might be surprising when you specify e.g. `MaxKeys=10` and want to iterate only over the 10 keys, yet the iterator will go over *all* matched keys, just with a new request to server each 10 keys.
  So, *if you just want e.g. the first three results, break off the loop manually, don't rely on the iterator*.

  (Unfortunately this is not clear in the docs (it's actually quite wrong), as the [library parameter description](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=MaxKeys#S3.Bucket.objects) is copied from the [API parameter description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html#RESTBucketGET-requests-request-parameters), where it actually makes sense: "*The response might contain fewer keys but will never contain more.*")